# Dependency's Jar not being deployed to Web Project

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, maven

I've got two Maven projects, **A**, that generates a jar, and **B**, that generates a war, in my Eclipse Workspace. **A** is a dependency of **B**, and, as such, is in **B**'s POM.

My problem is that **A** is not being deployed to a .jar in /lib/ when I run a Tomcat server with **B**.

It seems strange A appears in B's *Maven dependencies* as a folder, not as jar. Is this anomalous in some manner? If so, how can I fix it?

If this is not the problem, perhaps it's with Tomcat. Do I need to configure it somehow to accommodate this dependency schema (in which the dependency appears as a folder)?

Thanks!

--

EDIT: After manually exporting the .war file of **B**, I've discovered that **A** is being put in /lib/ as an empty .ear file.

Here is a screenshot of the dependency been displayed as a folder: [image]

Here are the relevant parts of the POM of A:

```
<groupId>br.com.reglare</groupId>
<artifactId>rule-model</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.8</version>
```

And B:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>br.com.reglare</groupId>
    <artifactId>rule-model</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

@urir: Yes, it fails to find a class defined in A: http://990fca173882239e.paste.se/

Comment: "A appears in B's Maven dependencies as a folder" yes, that does seem strange. Are you talking about the dependencies managed by Eclipse, or are you talking about the Maven POM? Since you didn't post any of the POMs, or an explanatory screenshot from Eclipse, we can't tell.

Comment: It's also hard to tell exactly what your question is. Does your WAR not run?

Comment: Can you post the pom configuration snippet and also have you unziped the war file to check if JAR A is present?

Comment: I dont think A should be deployed as jar to lib folder. If it appears in B depended project it should be enough to run Tomcat as server in eclipse. Do you have any actual error happening?

Comment: @parsifal: The war does not, as A is missing.

Comment: @Metalhead: it's not present: instead, there is an empty .ear file.

Comment: @urir: I've put the error in paste.se

Comment: Within Eclipse, did you check the Deployment Assembly of project B?

Comment: @HansBeemsterboer yes - the maven dependencies, which include project A, are there

Answer (score 0):

The dependency should be defined in your pom in this format:

```
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>xmlbeans</groupId>  
        <artifactId>xmlpublic</artifactId>  
        <version>2.2.0</version>  
    </dependency>
```

Also to view the dependecy tree use the 'dependency:tree' directive as follows:

```
mvn clean compile dependency:tree
```

If the dependecy is still not in the WEB-INF/lib folder of the war, then run the compile with the debugging flag and look for errors:

```
mvn -X clean compile
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's on Eclipse that I'd like to get the workflow right.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using m2e in eclipse to manage the webapp, you need to install [m2e-wtp](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/441371#.UHbl8enA8hE).  You should also be able to find it within eclipse in the marketplace.  It takes care of making sure that when you launch a maven web project through eclipse it gets all the dependencies in the right place.  Once you install the plugin, you may want to delete your project and import it again as an "existing maven project" then the plugin will get it all setup correctly.  Applying it after-the-fact has been iffy for me.

Comment: With it installed and everything done right, it still doesn't include the other project, and so I get the same error

Comment: you cleaned up everything from your previous deploy, including removing the app from tomcat and cleaning tomcat and tomcat work directory, and doing a refresh and clean on all projects?

Comment: Yep - I believe the problem is that I'm getting an empty .ear file from project A, when it gets exported